# Sampling distribution of Pearson correlation coefficient

Tags: correlation, sample, central-limit-theorem, pearson-r, sampling-distribution

Suppose I have draw a random sample of points $(x_i,y_i)$ iid from some distribution, then I compute the Pearson correlation coefficient $\overline{\rho}$ of the points in the sample.

Is $\overline{\rho}$ approximately normally distributed, if the sample size is large enough?  Is there a "Central Limit Theorem" for the sample correlation coefficient?

[This lesson](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat200/lesson/7/7.4) from Penn State's Stat 200 appears to say yes.  One doubt is that the correlation coefficient is bounded in the range $[-1,1]$, yet the normal distribution is unbounded, so $\overline{\rho}$ so can't be normally distributed; but perhaps it can be approximately normally distributed?

Comment: Hm. Aren't the conditions of the plan vanilla CLT satisfied for the sample correlation (the mean exists, and the variance is finite)? Then the CLT immediately gives you the convergence in distribution. What am I missing? Are you concerned about the variance of the sample correlation possibly being infinite (can that even happen?)?

Comment: @StephanKolassa, I might be missing something obvious, but: $\overline{\rho}$ is not the sum of iid r.v.'s, so I don't see how the CLT applies.

Comment: Ah. Duh. Sorry.

Comment: Some other version of CLT could still be applicable ...

Comment: @Kjetil That's correct.  When we view $\rho$ as the mean of the products $\xi_i \eta_i$ of the standardized variables, then intuitively as the sample size increases the standardization settles down to a constant affine transformation, whence the CLT applies.  This isn't terribly useful in practice, though, because it can take quite a large sample, especially with nonzero underlying correlations: usually one analyzes this in terms of the [Fisher Z transformation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation)

Comment: @whuber, perfect!  Thank you.  Want to write that as an answer?

Comment: I'm pretty sure an answer already exists on this site: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=fisher+z+transformation.